# API works in postman but receives cors error in React application

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I found an API that works in postman but, I cannot get it to return data in my application. I have attempted to add headers but, keep receiving a cors policy error.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TQxP.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARbed.png)

Here are the postman results
[postman results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs7lW.png)

Comment: Are you the owner of the api? The only way to fix that is change the source code of the api or config something in the server. You cannot anything by your side